# Is there an infinity or wild card for use of BETWEEN ranges with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a program where I'm accepting a range of input for a MySQL query of BETWEEN 1 and 100, for example. A user can select a range from the web page to cause a query to be BETWEEN 100 and (whatever infinity) would be. I don't want to change the MySQL query just for an infinity selection unless I have to. Is there a BETWEEN 100 and *? If so, what is the syntax? Thanks!

Comment: you can go up to `4294967295`, Maximum unsigned int value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no way to use wildcards in a BETWEEN clause. But you can use the minimum/maximum possible value for the type and this will achieve the same effect.

For example if you have a column that has type `BIGINT` (signed) then you can use `9223372036854775807` as the upper limit because this is the largest value possible for that datatype.

```
WHERE x BETWEEN 100 AND 9223372036854775807
```

The limits for integer values are listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types).

---

The other obvious solution is to use `>=` or `<=` instead of `BETWEEN` when one of the ends is unlimited. But as you said this requires changing the query.

```
WHERE x >= 100
```

---

There are also ways of avoiding changing the query by using a more complex query and providing NULL when you mean unlimited.

```
WHERE (x >= @lowerbound OR @lowerbound IS NULL)
AND (x <= @upperbound OR @upperbound IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest using this
when lower == null then it will be replaced by 0 and when upper is null then it will be replaced by a max bigint

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE 50 between ifnull(lower,0) and ifnull(upper,~0)
```