# How to customize Laravel whereBetween clause to make upper limit unlimited?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause, laravel-query-builder

I have been working on laravel using eloquent query builders. I have a situation in which I am filtering records based on search queries. I have an integer field, for which I want to filter data in ranges. User can select any of available ranges for example;
    `0-15`, `15-30` and `30 and above`.
For this purpose I found Query-builders whereBetween() clause very helping. But It becomes difficult for me for last option when I want to select for `30 and above`. 
I would really appreciate if someone could help me with some trick make this query

`->whereBetween('time_taken', [$lower-limit,$uper_limt])`

working for all cases. 
I don't want to write an additional line for this case, at which I can use simple where clause

`->where('time_taken','>=',$uper_limt)`.

Comment: Why can't you add the condition depending on input and just use `where` when the last option? Please post the entire Query Builder code.

Comment: I think this thread may also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767702/is-there-an-infinity-or-wild-card-for-use-of-between-ranges-with-mysql

Comment: @craig_h While the thread you suggested is pertinent to the question, it's a hack rather than a solution. As the accepted answer there states: using `where` is the way to go when you have only one boundary.

Comment: @Bogdan You are write but I have mentioned this option in my question as well. The thing is I don't want to write another if statement and where clause.

Comment: @tahirwaseer whats so hard in doing ->where vs ->whereBetween? give some good reason, it's even shorter

Answer (score 4):

The practical solution here is to just choose the appropriate SQL condition (I'm using a ternary operator here to keep it more compact):

```php
$query = App\Operation::query();

(empty($upper_limit)) ? $query->where('time_taken','>=', $lower_limit)
                      : $query->whereBetween('time_taken', [$lower_limit, $upper_limit]);

$results = $query->get();
```

Sure it would be nice to have just one line:

```
$results = App\Operation::whereBetween('time_taken', [$lower_limit, $upper_limit])->get();
```

But that's not possible in this case, not unless you want to extend the Laravel Query Builder and modify the way it handles empty parameters in the range passed as the value.

---

Writing clean and concise code is something we all strive to achieve, but one line solutions are not always possible. So my advice is to stop fixating (something I sometimes do myself) on things like this, because in some cases it's a lost cause that just ends up wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of these:

Method 1:

```
->whereBetween('time_taken', [$lower-limit,ModelName::max('time_taken')])
```

Method 2:

```
->whereBetween('time_taken', [$lower-limit,DB::table('table_name')->max('time_taken')])
```

Method 3:

```
$max = ModelName::max('time_taken');
//or
$max = DB::table('table_name')->max('time_taken');
//then
->whereBetween('time_taken', [$lower-limit,$max])
```

`max()` returns the highest value from your corespondent column.

Comment: While this keeps the one condition, it makes an additional query to the database to get the max value which is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @Bogdan I know, but he wanted it in one line.

Comment: Your answers are quite informative and for sure will help out somewhere in future. Thank you.